# Sending different data to different users with the same API endpoint

Tags: api, rest, authentication, endpoint

Let's say that users X and Y authenticate themselves (separately) on a service's REST API, and that JSON web tokens are used for authorization between the client and server. We want to send user-specific data to each user.

Should we ask the user to specify who they are, or should the server detect it based on the authentication method (in this case the payload on the JWT)?

In other words -

Should the API have endpoints that look like this:

GET /:user/resource (for example) /user_x/resource used by user X and /user_y/resource used by Y,

or would it be better to have

GET /resource and then, in the route handler, check the user id (as part of the JWT payload) return data based on the user id?

I'm not sure which of these (if either) is the best approach, or if there might be another way to do it, such as using query strings. It would be great to hear any opinions about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The server can identify the user based on either a session cookie, or an access-token. In your case, if you use a JWT, the user-information is usually already included in the token.
So the server should just fetch the information out of this token.

Just make sure, that you check the tokens signature on the backend.
Otherwise, an attacker could just modify the JWT and send a different user-id to the server.